# How do I get specify value type from psql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

in this psql database, one of the field stores information in the following format:

```
"phone"=>"12345","segment"=>"12345"
```

How can I query to get the value of just the `segment` category out?

I googled around and I know it's not an array, but I guess it's sth similar to it.

Thanks so much.

Comment: This is a terrible design. It's not even JSON.

Comment: Is it always phone and segment, or can that hold many different values?

Comment: Perform `\d+ tablename`  in the `psql` command-line tool.

Comment: I agree with @PM77-1, if that is a single column it is a terrible design. You can use a regexp to extract the fields and values, but it will considerably slow down the query, and add CPU overhead on the server side. Can you split this up into two columns? Oh, and do not use INT or INT8 for the phone number, because a number might start with 0, or might exceed your data type range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column always has (exactly) that format, you can use the [`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) extension to access each key individually.

Once you have [installed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html) it, you can cast that column to a `hstore` and the get the value of the key you want (e.g. `'segment'`)

```
select the_column::hstore -> 'segment'
from the_table;
```

You should really consider converting the column to a proper key/value hstore column.